# Get rows from DB with PHP, get the values from rows and insert in HTML

Tags: php

I want to get the rows from the DB that match the criteria, get specific values from each row and paste those values in different HTML. 
e.g. DB matches from criteria = row with id of 3, 7 and 30 
I want to take 'name' from row id 3 and put it in `<div id='firstResult'></div>` 
Then take 'name' from row id 7 and put it in `<div id='secondResult'></div>`
Finally, I want to take 'name' from row id 30 and put it in `<div id='thridResult'></div>`

I know how to put them in HTML, I'm struggling with the PHP part. So far I got:

```
<?php
    include_once 'databaseconn.php';

    $ramResult = $_POST['ram'];
    $graphcardResult = $_POST['graphcard'];
    $processorResult = $_POST['processor'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM laptops WHERE ram = '$ramResult' AND graphcard = '$graphcardResult' AND processor = '$processorResult' ;"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $nameResult = $row['name'];
            $ramResult = $row['ram'];
            $graphcardResult = $row['graphcard']; 
            $processorResult = $row['processor']; 
            $imgResult = $row['img'];  
            $imgId = $row['id'];
        }
    }
?>
```

I thought of giving the results numbers like first result is number 1, second is 2, etc. and then getting `$firstResult['name']` Not sure if this is the right approach and since I'm a newb I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this. I hope you can push me in the right direction.

for completion, DB:

```
id | name | ram | graph | processor | url
1  | data | data| data  | data      | data
2  | data | data| data  | data      | data
3  | data | data| data  | data      | data
```

etc..

Comment: Not sure did I get it right, but what's the problem to generate HTML "rows" within your `while` loop with the data you've fetched?

Comment: No, “numbered” variable names are usually not the correct approach. Go learn how to use _arrays_ for stuff like this.

Comment: And btw., your database query does not contain any ORDER BY clause - so the order in which you will get your records return, is not predictable. You should either explicitly order them, or make sure that you make the association by the actual record ID then. Otherwise, you might get what you _think_ should be the first value, as the second or third, etc.

Comment: @mitkosoft If I include a print_r($row) in the while loop it will correctly display all rows and values in it. I just don't know how to get a value from the first row, get a value from the second and get the value from the third so that I can put them in HTML. Or am I not understanding your question?

Comment: @04FS what I mean is simply a way to know which result was first, second and third. So first $row to come out if the result = $firstRow. From here I can enter the in html by using $firstRow['name'] for example. At the moment I do not know how to distinguish which row is first, second and third

Comment: As I said, put the data into an _array_ - and then use the appropriate index to access the values. Inside your while loop, `$data[] = $row;` (initialize $data as an empty array before the loop.) Afterwards, `$data[0]` then lets you access the first element of that array, `$data[1]` the second, and so on. (If basics like that really still need explaining to you, then you should probably go and work through a couple of beginner’s tutorials, that explain them?)

Comment: @04FS perfect that's exactly what I needed. I didn't know how to put it in an array in order to be able to call them by order. Also, yes indeed I need more education but not able to find examples on what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually speaking, you can achieve this a number of ways.

```
    <?php
    include_once 'databaseconn.php';

    $ramResult = $_POST['ram'];
    $graphcardResult = $_POST['graphcard'];
    $processorResult = $_POST['processor'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM laptops WHERE ram = '$ramResult' AND graphcard = '$graphcardResult' AND processor = '$processorResult' ;"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $list = mysqli_fetch_all ($result, MYSQLI_NUM); //RETURN INDEXED ARRAY
    //CREATES AN EMPTY STRING
    $output = "";
    if(count($list) > 0){ //CHECK IF THERE IS A RESULT.
    //if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        for($i=0; $i < count($list); $i++){
        //while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $nameResult = $list[$i]['name'];
            $ramResult = $list[$i]['ram'];
            $graphcardResult = $list[$i]['graphcard']; 
            $processorResult = $list[$i]['processor']; 
            $imgResult = $list[$i]['img'];  
            $imgId = $list[$i]['id'];
            //CONDITIONALLY CHECK VALUE AND ALTER OUTPUT
            if($i == "0"){
              // .= operator will append the string to the end of the existing string. 
              $output .= "<div id='firstResult'>".$nameResult."</div>";
            }elseif($i == "1"){
              $output .= "<div id='secondResult'>".$nameResult."</div>";
            }elseif($i == "2"){
              $output .= "<div id='thirdResult'>".$nameResult."</div>";
            }else{
              /*... default output ... */
            }
        }
      //ONCE OUTPUT IS BUILT, You can echo it, or use it in your template. 
      echo $output;

    }
?>
```

Comment: This is a very messy approach and will become a mess to maintain.  If you're looking to style the rows differently, I would recommend using a modulus operator and setting a class on every X element.  You may also create a counter and increment it within your while loop. outside of while $i=0; and then within while $i++;  This answers your question though.

Comment: but the thing is, I do not know which ImgId or which row id will be returned.

Comment: @number42, so what do you want to do with the data?  Do you only want to format those rows and display them if the id is 3, 7 or 30?  I mean if you want to limit the rows returned from mysql, you can edit your query.  Otherwise this will return all rows that match and you can filter based on the ID attributes you want to target.

Comment: What I want is when it returns the rows(I don't know which rows that will be) that I will be able to select data from the first row, second row and third row. e.g. get a specific value from first row of the result and put it somewhere, then, get a specific value from the second row of the result and put it somewhere else. 04FS gave me an answer in the comment here I can use `$data[] = $row;` so that then I can get a specific value from $data[0], then from $data[1], etc. I think this will do the trick, need to test it.

Comment: Updated the answer based on your clarifications. If you want to use a counter, use a counter.  Var_dump the output of $list to make sure your references are correct.